# "Where" method with "not nil" checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, notnull

How can I check if my variable is not nil when I use the "where" method ?

I tried these on a Product model that has a borrower_id field, but it didn't worked properly :

```rb
> Product.where("borrower_id.nil?")
> Product.where("borrower_id != nil")
> Product.where("borrower_id == !nil")
```

The only way I found was this one :

```rb
> Product.where("borrower_id > 0")
```

But it doesn't seem very clean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Product.where('borrower_id IS NOT NULL')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
> Product.where("borrower_id !=?", nil)
> Product.where("borrower_id !=?", "")
```